# How to get all attributes for the old version of a file in BOX account using V2 API?

Tags: box-api

I am doing some POC on box account using BOX v2 api. I need to get all attributes for the older version of a file..So I used request pattern like:https://api.box.com/2.0/files/FILE_ID/versions. But it gives me only the limited information of old versions. But i need to get all available attributes before the new version of file was uploaded.For example I should be able to get the attributes like version_number, descriptions and etc... of a specific version.Can someone help me to get this done?

Comment: What fields are you trying to get to.  Many of the fields, like the shared-links only exist at the parent level

Comment: @PlatformBoxer... I tried to get Descriptions,tags,comments,even the shared link...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently it doesn't look like there's a way to get the attributes for previous versions of a file. The only way you would be able to to this would be to make it current first.
http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-view-versions-of-a-file

Answer (score 0):

The descriptions, tags, shared link and comments don't belong to the version.

A file, is a holder of content.  When you upload a new version of the content into that holder, you don't also upload a new description from your file-system, because your old desktop filesystem doesn't have a description that it stores and uploads with every version of the file.

So we don't lose your description, or lose all the comments, just because you uploaded a new version of the same file.

That's why the version returned in the API doesn't include those thigns.  The description doesn't get versioned.  Nor do the comments.

The shared link downloads the current version of the file.  That way when you send someone a shared link, and they come back 2 months later, they get the latest version, not the old rough-draft of the file.